# Interesting convergence in divisor sums up to $10^k$

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $S(k)$ be the sum of divisors across each of $1, 2, ..., 10^k$.

For example, $$\begin{align}S(1) &= 1 + 3 + 4 + 7 + 6 + 12 + 8 + 15 + 3 + 17 \\&= 87\end{align}$$

where each of $1 + 3 + ... + 17$ are the sums of divisors of $1, 2, ..., 10^1$ respectively.

I noticed that as $k$ increases, the decimal expansion of $S(k)$ seems to "converge" to some number. For the first few values of $k$, computed using some suitable script, we have

$$\begin{align}
S(1) &=87\\
S(2) &=8299\\
S(3) &= 823081\\
...\\
S(10) &= 82246703352400266400\\
...\\
S(15) &=822467033424114009326065894639\\
S(16) &=82246703342411333689227187822414\\
S(17) &= 8224670334241132270081671519064067\\
\end{align}$$

If we take the decimal expansion of $S(k)$ as a fractional part and let this be $S'(k)$, we have

$$S'(\infty) = 0.82246703342411...$$

But hey!

$$\frac{\pi^2}{12} = 0.82246703342411...$$

So my question is this : Is the limit indeed $$S'(\infty) = \frac{\pi^2}{12}$$?

Comment: When you try a base other than 10, have you list $S(n)$ in to that base also?

Comment: @CYKwong To clarify, the "base" i mentioned is the base of the upper limit exponent. In the question i used base 10 because $S(k)$ is from $1$ to $10^k$, instead of say $1$ to $6^k$ in which the "base" here is $6$. However, the numbers are always printed out in decimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all due to the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\le x} \sigma(n) = \frac{\pi^2}{12}x + O(\log x).
$$
See [these notes](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m105f13/public_html/m105f13notes2.pdf) by Carl Pomerance (equation (5) if you're in a hurry).

Comment: Excellent find, thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome.  For more, grab any intro to analytic number theory text (ones by Apostol and Tenenbaum are great, for instance). Cheers!